# Overlay not affecting all areas of page

Tags: css

I'm trying to apply an overlay to create an effect similar to https://fancy.com when the login or signup link is clicked i.e the background should be dimmed.

The problem is that my nav bar and content boxes are not subjected to the overlay for some reason but not sure why?

I have created a fiddle to explain: https://jsfiddle.net/p861yfLp/1/

My Code:

```
<body>
  <div class="overlay">
    <nav>
      Menu
    </nav>
    <div id="content">
      <div class="box">
        Box
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: All content is inside the overlay  .. https://jsfiddle.net/p861yfLp/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change these files

**CSS** - set the position to absolute

```
.overlay {
      position: absolute;
}
```

EDIT: Following @DaniP answer the changes to the css are not required if you want a 'modal' feel for the overlay. Tho if you want to overlay everything I would recommend using the absolute position.

**HTML** - no need to make your overlay contain all other html

```
<body>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <nav>
        Menu
    </nav>
    <div id="content">
        <div class="box">
            Box
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Now your overlay will 'overlay'.

Comment: I am actually intending to use a modal

Comment: DaniP is right, @tommyd456 simple don't wrap the `overlay` with content, as I stated in my answer ;)

Comment: So you edit using other's answer? that's not nice :)

Comment: Still saying that I would use `position: absolute;` but letting him/her know its also possible using another way as stated by someone else, not tagging that user would not be nice ;)

Comment: I was referring that you use my answer, not DaniP comment mention `position:fixed`, because your edit is exactly like my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The half-black background-color is actually applied, but the nav (as child-element) has its own background-color (#FFF) defined. If you remove its background-color, it works:

```
.nav {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rw60gzbz/